# Include css in java (for href tag)

Tags: java, css, tags, href

I have to apply styles to my mail content (for href tags). My code is given below.

```
public void sendMailWithHsHeader(SentEmailDTO sendEmailDto)throws Exception {
        String css="";
        String mailHeader="";
        String mailfooter="";
        String mailContent=sendEmailDto.getContent();

        css="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>";
        css+="<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>";
        css+="<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>";
        css+="<style type='text/css'>";
        css+="a {color:#CCC; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 5px; font-size:.9em;}";
        css+="a:hover {color:#9F0;}";
        css+="</style></head><body>";

        mailHeader="<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' align='center' width='625'>"; 
        mailHeader+="<tr><td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #CCC;'><img src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/border-ul.jpg'/></td>"; 
        mailHeader+="<td style='border-top:1px solid #CCC;'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>";
        mailHeader+="<tr><td height='40' align='left'><a href='http://hiringsteps.com'><img border='0'"; 
        mailHeader+="src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/hiring-steps.jpg'/></a></td></tr><tr><td align='center' style='background-color:#1E314E;'><img src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/line.jpg'/></td>";        
        mailHeader+="</tr></table></td><td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #CCC;'><img src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/border-ur.jpg'/></td>";
        mailHeader+="</tr><tr><td width='20'></td><td height='300' align='left' valign='top' style='background-color:#F0F0F0; font:14px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px 20px; line-height:1.3em;'>";        

        mailfooter+="</td><td width='20'></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td align='left' valign='bottom' style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;'><img src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/border-ll.jpg'></td>";
        mailfooter+="<td valign='bottom' style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>";
        mailfooter+="<tr><td align='center' style='background-color:#1E314E; font:14px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px 20px; line-height:1.3em;'>";        
        mailfooter+="<p><a href='http://hiringsteps.com'>HOME</a><a href='http://hiringsteps.com/Features.html'>FEATURES</a><a href='http://hiringsteps.com/Pricing.html'>PRICING</a><a href='http://hiringsteps.com/About-Us.html'>ABOUT US</a><a href='http://hiringsteps.com/Contact-Us.html'>CONTACT US</a></p>";
        mailfooter+="<p><span style='font-size:.9em; color:#CCC;'>follow us</span> <a href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hiring-Steps/155650987881886'><img border='0' align='absmiddle' src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/fb.jpg'/></a> <a href='https://twitter.com/#!/Hiringsteps'><img border='0' align='absmiddle' src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/tw.jpg'/></a> <a href='http://www.linkedin.com/company/2630770'><img border='0' align='absmiddle' src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/in.jpg'/></a> <a href='http://hiringsteps.com/Signin.html'>";
        mailfooter+="<img border='0' align='absmiddle' src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/login.jpg'/></a></p></td></tr><tr>";               
        mailfooter+="<td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td align='right' valign='bottom' style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;'><img src='http://hiringsteps.com/email/images/border-lr.jpg'/></td>";       
        mailfooter+="</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='center'><p style='color:#777; font:11px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>&copy; Copyright 2012 HiringSteps. All rights reserved.<br>2321 Rosecrans Avenue, Suite 4270, El Segundo, CA 90245</p></td>";
        mailfooter+="<td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></body></html>"; 

        sendEmailDto.setContent(css+mailHeader+mailContent+mailfooter);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        setProperties(props);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);

        session.setDebug(true);
        // create a message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        // set the from and to address
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(sendEmailDto.getFromAddress());
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

        String to = sendEmailDto.getToAddress();
        String[] toAddress = to.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddress[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        if(sendEmailDto.getCcAddress()!= null) {
            if(!sendEmailDto.getCcAddress().equals("")) {
                String cc = sendEmailDto.getCcAddress(); 
                String[] ccAddress = cc.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

                InternetAddress[] addressCC = new InternetAddress[ccAddress.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < ccAddress.length; i++)
                {
                    addressCC[i] = new InternetAddress(ccAddress[i]);
                }           
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCC);
            }
        }           

        InternetAddress[] replyTo = new InternetAddress[1];
        replyTo[0]=new InternetAddress("noreply@hiringsteps.com");      
        msg.setReplyTo(replyTo);
        msg.setSubject(sendEmailDto.getSubject());
        // Now the message body.
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

        BodyPart pixPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        setBodyParts(sendEmailDto, msg, mp, pixPart);

        Transport.send(msg);
}



public void setBodyParts(SentEmailDTO sendEmailDto, Message msg,Multipart mp, BodyPart pixPart) throws MessagingException {     
        String content=sendEmailDto.getContent();       
        content=content.replace("\n", "<br />\n");
        pixPart.setContent(content, "text/html");
        pixPart.addHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        mp.addBodyPart(pixPart);
        msg.setContent(mp);     
}
```

Here in line 4 starting with mailFooter, I have to apply style to hreg tag, which is in css string. But the style is not getting applied. Please help me..

Comment: Are you aware that you are sending an empty mailHeader?

Comment: Yes.. I have now edited. I just skipped that for the readability here.

Comment: First step - forget about the Java bit.  Capture the value of `css+mailContent+mailFooter`, stick it in an email manually, and see if this is rendered as you want.  If not, tweak it until it works, then generate *that*.  If it does, then obviously your `sendEmailDto` is not passing the raw string through as you'd expect.

Comment: how to stick it in an email manually?

Comment: all other part is working. The content in css string is only not working. The href styles cannot be set as inline as it will block the mouse over styles.

Answer (score 2):

You want these bad-boys in your header, otherwise it doesn't know it will be HTML-formatted.

`Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: You have since edited and removed the header entirely, is it being set correctly?

Comment: I have also set 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' in my code at line 8

Comment: That's the `<head>` tag inside the HTML, not the emails header. The emails header has to specify that the content will be HTML, otherwise it won't be formatted on the receiving end.

Comment: How to specify the email header.?

Comment: That depends how you're actually sending this email, which you haven't posted the code for

Comment: What's the BodyPart object? You should edit your original post, and put the full code in there.